# How long does it take to get a Netherlands visa?

Tags: visas, netherlands, schengen-visas

I'm an Indian citizen and have read that it takes 15 days to get the Netherlands visa, but some people told me that they got their visa in 2-3 days. Is that possible? What is the norm?

I have only 10 days left before my trip and I have an appointment on the 16th. Am I correct that they'll take my passport and, by the time they decide, it will still be with them?

Comment: As I said previously just call them and tell your situation

Comment: Called them. They said 15days is the decision making period. People get it quick, but some people get it after 15days too. Thanks. Hence there is a risk of my passport stuck at Netherland consulate office on the day of travel to the USA. So not applying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After submission, it can take anywhere from several days to several weeks, or it can take longer. That's the norm, that it takes however long it takes, and it's understandable that you're anxious, as you want to travel shortly. With your appointment in several days, they will either immediately return your passport, or take it and tell you when to come back and get it.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided not to apply. I'll be traveling the USA on 24th. Can I apply while in the USA ?? I'll be staying in USA three weeks (24t-15th July). Thereafter I have an interview in Netherlands 21st July in a week time (for which I'll require a Visa). This is a career opportunity hence I'm anxious.

Comment: Where do you travel, NL visa can be obtained in three places in the US. But I would apply in the US if there is an opportunity and also give all explanations why you're applying in the different country. And don't forget to call them first to check, might save you time and money.

Comment: @Pushpa If you have a job interview in Holland, you're taking a bit of a risk, as the general Schengen rule is that you apply where you are resident. What happens is you don't get the visa?